# Can't find 1-inch to 1.25-inch flexible coupling

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

After mice chewed through my stock thin plastic dishwasher drain line, (ruining our kitchen floor, leading to a homeowners claim), I'm replacing that line. I refuse to use the cheap, stock dishwasher drain lines. Besides being too short, mice could chew through them again. We have extra cabinetry between the dishwasher and sink, making this a longer-than-usual run.

I have some new, black, thick, reinforced hose that mice will not chew through. This new hose is 1 inch OD, and 5/8 inch ID which will slip onto the sink garbage disposal perfectly.

The dishwasher drain outlet is unthreaded, and 1.25 inch (1-1/4") diameter. Thus, it is larger than the OD of the hose I'm using. Connecting the hose to that drain outlet is the trick.

What I wish for is a 1-inch to 1.25-inch flexible coupling, since that plus two hose clamps would render this job complete. But despite many attempts (both online and at multiple plumbing supply places), I've found no such part. This is close, but is the wrong size:

[https://www.amazon.com/Fernco-PDTC-150-2-Inch-Drain-Connector/dp/B000BQL17Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQL17Y)

As a further constraint, I do not want to insert anything into the new hose that would reduce the ID. I've already burned out one pump in this dishwasher due to debris clogging at the drain hose connections.

So the question I have is this: how can I create a solid connection between this hose (1" OD) and the dishwasher drain outlet (1.25" OD)?

Comment: You may need to forego the rubber drain outlet fitting and connect directly to the hose, or remove the hose completely and connect to the outlet fitting. At any rate, this is more or less a shopping question, which we prefer to leave to the search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Call an appliance parts supplier with the model # of the dishwasher, they probably stock the drain hose although they may provide both sections, drain pump to discharge, discharge to waste line (garbage disposal). You should be able to buy what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jeff of NER has the best answer. If that doesn't work for you then you should use a barbed hose fitting to connect flexible rubber hose, the fitting goes inside the hose and you clamp the hose to the fitting. The item you linked is for joining hard plastic or metal and may squish the rubber hose and cause a leak. You may have a difficult time finding a barbed fitting with 5/8" on one side and 1" or 1 1/4" on the other side. So you would get two barbed fittings that are threaded and join them together. For hose you can go to an auto supply store and buy heater hose, comes in all the sizes you mentioned

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using anything that reduces the ID on the drain hose. I previously had two hoses joined by a 2-inch length of copper pipe, and that was still enough to collect dishwasher debris to the point of clogging it enough to burn out the dishwasher pump. The hose I have is extremely thick and firm (mouse resistant). But I appreciate the ideas and will keep them in mind!